# WINRT How to declare a file type association for a file without extension

Tags: windows-runtime

How can i access a file "without" extension in metro application?

Normally you would need to declare the capabilities of the application incl. a declaration which filetype/extension you wanna access, if the file is located in the document library. The problem is the file i wanna access dont have an extension.

Im trying to access some files within a git directory.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want your application to launch when the user clicks on any file without an extension? That's what the extensions in the app manifest specify. Otherwise, just say that you want to access the documents library and specify * as the filename filter on the file picker dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has always used the file extension for association with a program. A file without an extension cannot be associated with a program.